# how to find element with specific class attributes using css selector or any other locator selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, class, css-selectors, element

Am trying to find an element using attribute in the same class,below is the element of the

```
div class="outcome-pricedecimal " data-markettypecategory="00000000-0000-0000-da7a-000000580001" data-pd="1.66">1.66 </div>
```

I want to locate it using the data-pd="1.66"
it the decimal number i need, because i want it to find the element if the decimal has changed to my prefered value(e.g finding data-pd when =1.05)
I tried finding it using this codes

```
driver.find elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(number()
```

driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.data-pd="1.05)"and not:(.outcome-pricedecimal) (.data-markettypecategory="00000000-0000-0000-da7a-000000580001)"]')[0].click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(div.1.01)

thanks as you answer and help...

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[data-pd='1.66']") Something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `BeautifulSoup` for this. Here is the code to do it using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="outcome-pricedecimal " data-markettypecategory="00000000-0000-0000-da7a-000000580001" data-pd="1.66">1.66 </div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

div = soup.find('div')

data_pd = div['data-pd']

print(data_pd)
```

Output:

```
1.66
```

If you still wanna do it with `selenium`, then you can do it like this:

```
data_pd = driver.find_element_by_class_name("outcome-pricedecimal ").get_attribute('data-pd')

print(data_pd)
```